# How to calculate the drag of inclined object?

Tags: drag, aerodynamics

For example, we have inclined flat panel in the plane that is parallel to the wind:

[image]

We can split the velocity into V1 = V * sin(α) and V2=V * cos(α)
then calculate two Re numbers and two Cd coefficients from V1 and V2
( for example using the xfoil simulation program )

Then we split the dynamic pressure q = (V^2 * ρ)/2 into q1=q * sin(α) and q2=q * cos(α)

and calculate the forces like F1 = q1 * Cd1 * A and F2 = q2 * Cd2 * A

Also for symmetrical object like sphere and α = 45°

Cd1 = Cd2 = Cd so

F1 = q * sin(α) * Cd * A = F * sin(α)

F2 = q * cos(α) * Cd * A = F * cos(α)

and the equation F^2=F1^2 + F2^2 also works

If this is wrong approach then why ?

If this is right approach then where is it already described ?

If it works then how to find the book or article with samples of its applications ?